# Passar elementos SVG dinamicos para ficheiro

Tags: php, javascript, svg

Crio elementos (circulos) SVG com o código JavaScript dinamicamente. O problema é que quero passar esses circulos para um ficheiro com extensão .svg. Se cria-se os elementos no html, seria so copiar para o ficheiro, passado variaveis de posição de cada um. Mas como são criados dinamicamente, como posso mostra-los num ficheiro svg para depois poder abrir com um programa de edição. Exemplo como crio:

```
<line title="Vertical" x1=60 y1=60 x2=60 y2=460 stroke-width=2 stroke=black />
```

E no ficheiro para criar é:

```
    fwrite($hndl, "<line title='Vertical' x1='60' y1='60' x2='60' y2='460' stroke-width='2' stroke='black' /> \n");
```

Agora com o codigo dinamicamente:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
    var x = stepX * (i + 1);
    var y = stepY * (i + 1);

    //create circle
    var shape = document.createElementNS(
        "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
    shape.setAttributeNS(null, "cx", originX + x);
    shape.setAttributeNS(null, "cy", originY - y);
    shape.setAttributeNS(null, "r", 5);
    shape.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "green");
    shape.setAttributeNS(null, "class", "draggable");
    shape.setAttributeNS(null, "order", i);
    shape.setAttributeNS(null, "id", i);
    shape.id="circle"+i;
    svg.appendChild(shape);
    }
```

Como posso passa-los para o ficheiro?

Answer (score -1):

Bom, se entendi bem você quer que seu usuário crie uma imagem SVG dinamicamente com Javascript e então quer criar essa imagem no servidor com PHP, né?

Se for, basta você fazer um formulário e enviar os dados que quiser para ele.

Aqui vai um exemplo (simples, sem validação nem nada) de como poderia ser o formulário:

### HTML

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin: 0;
}

input {
    display: block;
}
</style>

<form action="writesvg.php" method="get">
    <label for="name">Nome do arquivo</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Digite o nome do arquivo SVG">

    <label for="radius">Tamanho do circulo</label>
    <input type="number" name="radius" id="radius">

    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

### PHP

```
<?php
if( isset($_GET['name']) && isset($_GET['radius']) ) {

    $r = $_GET['radius'];
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    $size = $r *2;
    $shape = "<circle cx='$r' cy='$r' r='$r'  />";
    $svg = "<?xml version='1.0'?><svg width='$size' height='$size' version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>$shape</svg>";
    $fp = fopen("$name.svg", "w");

    fwrite($fp, $svg);
    fclose($fp);

};
?>
<img src="<?= $name?>.svg">
```

Para ficar mais dinâmico, você pode trabalhar com `AJAX`, para enviar o formulário e depois é só inserir a imagem via Javascript na página, sem a necessidade de um refresh.

Comment: Os elementos ja são criados dinamicamente,como esta no codigo antes de serem passados para o ficheiro. Quero fiquem em codigo SVG dentro do ficheiro(svg) para depois poder editar com um software.